# Difference between set -g and set -x

Tags: fish

I'm currently migrating from bash configs over to fish and got stuck translating my over bash exports. It seems there's three ways to do it in Fish that get the job done but I can't tell which one I should use, or if they have side effects I am unaware of

```
set -g VAR value
set -x VAR value
set -xg VAR value
```

Surely they do not all do the same thing. Can someone explain what the differences are and in which situations each is appropriate, please?

Comment: Typing `set -h` will show the meanings under scope options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not all do the same thing. The `-x` flag is orthogonal to the `-g`, `-l`, and `-u` flags. The former simply sets the export attribute on the var. The latter three set the scope of the var. You can have a global, unexported, `VAR` and inside a function do `set -lx VAR value` to create a locally scoped instance that is exported. When control returns from the function the global scope `VAR` pops back into existence and it won't be exported.

If you're using a recent version (2.7, maybe 2.6) you can do `set --show VAR` to display the values in all three scopes and whether or not each one is exported.

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean for a variable to be exported?

Comment: An exported variable is visible to commands run by your fish shell. Do `set -g NOT_EXPORTED abc; set -gx EXPORTED def; env | grep EXPORTED`. Note that `env` is an external command that shows the exported variables it inherited. It should show that only the var created via `set -gx` is present.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Kurtis. That's what I figured, but now I am confused why I can see the environment variables I set inside my config.fish using `set -g`?

Comment: If the variable is already exported then `set -g` retains the exported attribute. So if, for example, you're doing something like `set -g PATH /dir1 /dir2 $PATH` it will remain exported because it was in the exported environment when fish started running.

Comment: I did previously define my variable with -x before for testing and didn't delete that line, expecting it to get overwritten in my next declaration of my variable. Thank you so much Kurtis! It all makes sense to me now :)